# Using "ce" instead of "cette"

Tags: adjectifs, démonstratifs

I came about this phrase:

> Cette diversité

If I use *ce* instead of *cette*, would that be wrong?

Comment: Diversité is [feminine](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/diversit%C3%A9), You don't use  *ce* in front of a feminine noun. Here's the rule: in [French](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-23648.php) and in [English](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/french/grammar/possessivead/demonstrativeadrev1.shtml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well "ce" is masculine and "cette" is feminine.